# 404 error with wordpress ssl

Tags: wordpress, ssl, http-status-code-404

SSL was installed on our server and our site is mostly wordpress and there are some non-wordpress pages which work fine with https:// and the home page works as well, but when I try to access a wordpress page/post I get 404 page not found error. I did try the wordpress https plugin to force ssl on certain pages and I got the same error. Also I do have custom permalinks. Any way to force ssl on certain wordpress pages?
Regards,
J.

Comment: This looks like an URL rewriting problem.

If you are using Apache, verify...
1) That your .htaccess file is present and readable by the web server's user.
2) That your Apache config as the proper AllowOverride setting to allow URL rewriting.
3) That the mod_rewrite module is installed enabled.

If you're not using Apache, which web server is your SSL site running on?

Comment: Thanks! You were right - it was issue#2. After setting AllowOverride to All it worked right.

Answer (score 36):

The `directory` tag is required in ssl virtual host config of apache same as of http port 80, to allow override redirect rules using `.htaccess` of wordpress.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ..
    ..
    ..
    <Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Works like charm. However I'm surprised the non http conf works without the `<Directory />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's not WordPress-specific, but you could set the `$_SERVER` value to enable SSL.  Add the following in your wp-config.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

This would at least let you figure out if you have your server configured properly or you have some other WordPress-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Ankit Sharma's answer is good in 2023 too, just add that `<Directory>` tag and its content and change the document root as per yours and you'll get your login page back. The file name might have changed since then, so this is the file to alter  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

Also , we need to make sure that `Documentroot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf` is set to `/var/www/html/wordpress`

And restart apache2 `sudo service apache2 restart`